# Deploy Java restful web service to live server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, weblogic12c

I have just learned to create java rest API using jersey and Oracle database.
I'm developing in eclipse and using weblogic server to run and test web service on localhost.

**My question is what are the options of live servers to deploy this service so that I can access this API in my android application or any web application???**

Comment: Package Your project as WAR and deploy it on any Servlet Container ( eg; Tomcat, Jetty etc.) You can get VPS or get one AWS virtual machine and run your own servlet container and place your war inside the "webapp" folder.

Comment: Thank you @HaridasN for the reply.
Can I deploy my web service which I have deployed on weblogic (localhost) to Tomcat or jetty servlet container?? or It has nothing to do with that?
If yes then Can you please provide me a link or some material where I can  find information about this.?
I have searched a lot on google but I'm not able to figure out how exactly is this thing going to work out.
I'm sorry If I'm asking much.
I'm totally a noob in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that. But you have to make sure that all the dependent jars are packaged with the your WAR project(eg; Oracle db related things).

Some blog entries which give you an idea about what are all these servers and which one to pick for open development and common standards - http://blogs.forrester.com/mike_gualtieri/11-07-15-stop_wasting_money_on_weblogic_websphere_and_jboss_application_servers,

and this one http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-great-java-application-server-debate-with-tomcat-jboss-glassfish-jetty-and-liberty-profile/

This will give pretty good idea about what is all these servers :)

Comment: Thanks, this gives clear idea about these servers.
One more question.
Don't jar files automatically be included when I create WAR file of the project?

Comment: Yes it will automatically adds dependent  jars into the war file  while creating the war project.